# PDO INSERT do not register duplicated records inside mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Hello I have te following PDO insert into database function, how I can check if there is such a recored inside the database already to give error that the user is already registred with this information ? My table is organized like that

```
id | curso_id | user_id 
1  | 12       | 43
2  | 5        | 56
```

so if a combination of curso_id = 12 and user_id = 43 is inside the database do not register second one of this kind, give error.

```
$userid = $_SESSION['userID'];  
$cursoid = $_GET["id"];

try {

          $con = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD ); //our new PDO Object
          $con->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
          $stmt = $con->prepare( "Insert Into subscriptions ( curso_id, user_id ) Values ('$cursoid', '$userid')" );
          $stmt->execute();

       } catch (PDOException $e) {
              echo "I'm sorry there is a problem with your operation.."; $e->getMessage(); //catch and show the error
       }

$con = null;
header( 'Location: cursos.php' ) ;
}
```

Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: Just a side comment,you are not using prepared statements.

Comment: $userid is coming from the loged user in the session. and $cursoid is coming from another database sqlquery which is showing the articles in the database

Comment: the idea is to compate the both columns and if there is a match on what you are inserting do give error, To not put duplicated records. $userid it will be always > than 0 because on every insert you are inserting something on the both columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a UNIQUE index : `unique( curso_id, user_id )` constraint .
 And then you can use query something like this with `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` clause :

```
INSERT INTO subscriptions
    ( curso_id, user_id )
    VALUES
    ('12', '43')
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE user_id = user_id;
```

If the `affected-rows` is `1` , a new row is inserted .
If the `affected-rows` is `2` , an existing row is updated .

Based on the affected-rows value , you can choose to display appropriate message to the user .
...

[INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)
[REPLACE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html)
[Insert to table or update if exists (MySQL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205181/insert-to-table-or-update-if-exists-mysql)

Comment: using this method can I update both statements something like UPDATE user_id = user_id; AND curso_id = curso_id; ?

Comment: okay I did figured it out and now it is working excelent, thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Proactively**, *look before you leap*. Execute a `select` before inserting, which will show you if there's already a relevant record.

**Reactively**, add a `unique(curso_id,user_id)` constraint to your table. That would protect your data when everything else fails...